# Pods assigned to node with no role

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am currently doing some scenarios on Katacoda and I am curious about the node roles.

My cluster has 2 nodes and one has the role Master and the other has no role.

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
controlplane   Ready    master   5m11s   v1.18.0
node01         Ready    <none>   4m40s   v1.18.0
```

Now when I look at the pods in my cluster, it seems like all three pods are assigned to node01

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
random-logger-7687d48b59-jftl9   1/1     Running   0          26s    10.244.1.5   node01   <none>           <none>
random-logger-7687d48b59-mwz4h   1/1     Running   0          26s    10.244.1.4   node01   <none>           <none>
random-logger-7687d48b59-vgbc8   1/1     Running   0          117s   10.244.1.3   node01   <none>           <none>
```

My understanding is that the scheduler puts pods on notes that are assigned the worker role, so why are they being scheduled on a node with no role? Is a node with no role in the cluster assumed to be a worker node?

Answer (score 1):

use `kubectl describe nodes my-node` to see the details of the node

A node `role` is just a label with the format node-role.kubernetes.io/

You can add this yourself with 'kubectl label'